# Error with combining lists

Tags: list-manipulation, data

I'm attempting to combine lists of the form

```
In: PressureChange = Data[[All,{3}]]//ToExpression;
Out: {{0.19}, {0.19}, ... etc }}

In: TempChange = Subtract[TempTwo,TempOne]//ToExpression;
Out: {{0.22}, {0.22} ... etc}}
```

Where Data is a list of many { TempOne, TempTwo, PressureChange } values. All Lists are the same size.

I need a form of {{ TempChange1 , PressureChange1 },{ TempChange2 , PressureChange2 } etc ...

My issue is when I try to use the Riffle command, followed by Partition,

```
Input: AB = Riffle[{TempChange}, {PressureChange}]
Output: {{{0.22}, {0.22}, etc ...}}
```

The output is not a Riffle of my data. Rather, one list followed by the other. I'm assuming it's because the data output appears as individual {} inside one big {    }.

Is there any way to change the output to work better with this sort of problem? Or should I do it by hand, by re-formatting the output manually every time?

Comment: `Transpose[{Flatten@TempChange, Flatten@PressurChange}]` or `Riffle[PressureChange, TempChange]~Partition~2`

Comment: Ah, thankyou! I never understood the Transpose function properly. That's perfect.